# use twitter timeline widget in ionic framework

Tags: ios, angularjs, twitter, ionic-framework

I developing app in ionic and need include a timeline of hashtag in view,

in web, work perfectly but if i try use in iphone or emulator from xCode not work

someone has a idea of some library or alternative for get a timeline in a view?

(i not need authenticate or share for twitter only show the timeline widget like web)

Comment: When you get this answered, do let me know please!

Answer (score 0):

Only for IOS,

https://github.com/etiennea/phonegap-twitter-plugin

its the only way i find

Answer (score 0):

Plugin Based in eriennea work, but add support to Android and Angular factory to use from Ionic

https://github.com/jmtt89/cordovaTwitter